# how does google create the instant preview images?

Tags: google-instant-previews

I was wondering how google is capturing all those websites that are featured in google's instant preview? I'm sure they are not using a thumbnail service (like www.thumbalizr.com, websnapr.com, snapcasa.com, thumbshots.com) but rather use their own software. BUT: given that google captures A LOT of websites, they must have a very sophisticated system. PLUS: this generates HUGE amounts of data (jpgs?).
Does somebody have more insight into how google does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say, but here's some info from a Google project manager discussing it:

http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/11/beyond-instant-results-instant-previews.html

It says in part:

> "we match your query with an index of the entire web, identify the
>   relevant parts of each webpage, stitch them together and serve the
>   resulting preview completely customized to your search—usually in
>   under one-tenth of a second"

That plus looking at the source of a preview page suggests that they're using their own index (the same webcache.googleusercontent.com that is used to serve the Cached pages) to serve JPEG Base64 image strings as screenshots.

Comment: just to make sure I understand you correctly: so you think they actually grab the html code (plus images) of the website and then push it as a jpeg to the end user?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's something like that.  Their webmaster pages hint that they render the page with the same engine Chrome uses, and the preview is based on the result.